# Can an energy-momentum four vector include the quantities of all objects in a closed system?

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, momentum, conservation-laws, inertial-frames

Say I have a particle moving along the $x$-axis in the Earth's reference frame.  It decays into an upsilon and a proton, each of which has an energy of 60 GeV.  They are traveling in opposite directions.  The proton has a mass of 1 (or 1GeV/c^2) and the upsilon has a mass of 10 (or 10GeV/c^2).

My question is; can I set the four-vector of the original particle as:

$(E, Px, Py, Pz)$

And the four-vector of the decay particles as one general vector:

$(E', Px', Py', Pz')$

Such that $E'=120$GeV, the total energy of the two decay particles?  Or, to find the energy and momentum of each particle, would I have to have two separate four-vectors and calculate them using the inner product?

Comment: energy and momentum are conserved in interactions, and each particle is described by a four vector. Four vector algebra follows the vector rules of addition etc.see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among the properties of vectors is that they have an addition operation, so you can certainly add two or more four-vectors together.

More over that is a useful operation: the result represents the total energy and momentum of the system.

But it goes one step further: the (invariant) mass of a system is found from the square of the *system's*  four-momentum just like the (invariant) mass of a particle is found from the square of its four-momentum.